# Исключение данных из выборки

Tags: sql

есть таблица в google bigquery

```
email sales date

email_1 100 2016-02-05 00:00:00  
email_1 100 2016-03-10 00:00:00  
email_2 100 2016-04-02 00:00:00
```

нужно исключить все email у которых первая дата регистрации < 2016-03-01.
Если сделать обычный фильтр по дате в where, то исчезнет только email_1 за февраль, а нужно чтобы email_1 полностью исключить т.к. первая дата регистрации < 2016-03-01

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
  from table
 where email not in(select email from table where date<'2016-03-01')
```

Или, как вариант (возможно будет быстрее в каких то случаях):

```
select A.*
  from table A
  left join table B on B.date<'2016-03-01' and B.email=A.email
 where A.email is null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT email
FROM table
GROUP BY email
HAVING MIN(date) >= '2016-03-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table t2
                  WHERE t1.email = t2.email
                  AND t2.date < '2016-03-01' 
                 )
```